# How to test all radio button / check box were checked before submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used `form_tag` to build a form, which display questions and answers for user can check. This is my form:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: 'exams', action: 'check_results' }, authenticity_token: true) do %>
  <ol class="questions">
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <li class="content_question"><%= kramdown question.content %></li>

  <ol class="answers">
    <% question.answers.shuffle.each do |answer| %>
      <table class="answer_contents">
        <tbody>
      <tr>
        <% if question.question_type.shorcut == 'MC' %>
          <td><%= check_box_tag "user_answer_ids[#{question.id}][]", answer.id, false, id: "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}" %></td>
          <td><li></li></td>
          <td><%= label_tag "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}", kramdown(answer.content) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td><%= radio_button_tag "user_answer_ids[#{question.id}][]", answer.id, false, id: "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}" %></td>
          <td><li></li></td>
          <td><%= label_tag "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}", kramdown(answer.content) %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
    <% end %> <%# question.answers %>
  </ol> <%# ol.answers %>
  <br>
   <% end %> <%# @questions %>
   </ol> <%# ol.questions %>
  <%= submit_tag "Finish Exam", disable_with: "Checking results...", confirm: "Are you sure?", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %> <%# form_tag %>
```

I want to check if user forget to check some questions, when they press submit, it will have a alert for user to check miss question. Anyone can help/guide me how can I do that with javascript or jquery? Thanks.

**HTML Code generated**

This is html for one question and its answers, with radio select. With checkbox, it has different is, has more `table` element, and `type` in `input` is **checkbox** instead of **radio**.

```
<li class="content_question"><p>What is the term used to describe a framework of the phase involved in developing information systems?</p>
</li>
<ol class="answers">
  <table class="answer_contents">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="user_answer_ids_663" name="user_answer_ids[186][]" type="radio" value="663"></td>
        <td><li></li></td>
        <td><label for="user_answer_ids_663"><p>systems development life cycle (t)</p></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="answer_contents">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="user_answer_ids_664" name="user_answer_ids[186][]" type="radio" value="664"></td>
        <td><li></li></td>
        <td><label for="user_answer_ids_664"><p>extreme programing</p></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="answer_contents">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="user_answer_ids_665" name="user_answer_ids[186][]" type="radio" value="665"></td>
        <td><li></li></td>
        <td><label for="user_answer_ids_665"><p>rapid application development</p></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="answer_contents">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input id="user_answer_ids_666" name="user_answer_ids[186][]" type="radio" value="666"></td>
        <td><li></li></td>
        <td><label for="user_answer_ids_666"><p>predictive life cycle</p></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</ol>
```

Comment: can anyone explain why this is downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example below adds a handler to the form `myForm`'s submit event so you need to give your form the ID `myForm`. This checks that each question has one of it's possible answers checked. It works for both radio and checkbox answers. If validation fails, it alerts the list of questions that are missing an answer, then prevents the form from submitting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){

        var errors = [];

        $('.content_question').each(function(){

            var answerCont = $(this).next();
            var inputs = $(answerCont).find('input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]');

            if(inputs.length > 0)
            {
                var groupChecked = false;

                $(inputs).each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked'))
                    {
                        groupChecked = true;
                    }
                });

                if(!groupChecked)
                {
                    errors.push($(this).text().trim());
                }
            }
        });

        if(errors.length > 0)
        {
            var errorMessage = "You missed " + errors.length + " questions: \n\n";

            for(var i=0; i<errors.length; i++)
            {
                errorMessage += errors[i] + "\n";
            }
            alert(errorMessage);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have update html code, this is just one block html of one question and its answers.

Comment: Some questions have checkboxes too.

Comment: it has the same structure like radio, but it has more table element and has `type` in `input` element is **checkbox** instead of **radio**. The `id` of `input` also has the same structure.

Comment: thanks, I will try your code. So, if I press submit button but the form has some radio/checkbox were not checked, the page will alert right now, or the page have to reload and alert after that?

Comment: The page will alert right now, the form will not submit until all questions are answered.

Comment: Woooooow, your code worked right now without modify anything, I'm so crazyyyy :D. It's alert content of quesstions were not checked. I think I can learn many things from your code. Thank you so so so muchhhh, although thanks is not enough for you :D